# embed a html page into Wordpress without using iframe

Tags: jquery, html, wordpress

I have a html page(styled with bootstrap and has some jquery functions in it). I want to integrate this to wordpress site. I dont want to use iframes for this purpose.

Is there a way to embed this html file into wordpress page without using iframes or plugins?

I'm beginner in WordPress. I checked the custom page templates, but not sure how to do it. Can any one please help me with this?

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: just put `<?php include_once('theHTMLpage.html');?>` where you want to include the page, obviously ensure the path to the file is correct.

Comment: @Billy Thanks. I will try it. Is it so simple? I just need to create a custom page template with the above line.

Answer (score 0):

use JQuery Ajax to load your html

Comment: so i need to include .load("myhtmlpage.html") in the custom page template?